# JNI C++ call onCreate JAVA - Facebook

Tags: android, c++, facebook, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I create a game on cocos2dx with C++, now I want to connect it with Facebook, to accomplish this I do it with JAVA and then connect it with JNI. Both things works perfectly, but to connect it with Facebook I need to @override the method onCreate(), but I don't know how to call that method from C++ JNI.

When I move my Facebook code to a new function I need to execute this

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {}
```

But "this" doesn't exist outside onCreate(). Any ideas?

1-. How to login with Facebook, without calling something on the method onCreate() {}

2-. How to call from JNI C++ to the method onCreate?

My JNI code:

It call FacebookLogin, and works fine, but no with onCreate

```
if(JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(minfo,
                                      "com/company/game/Facebook",
                                      "facebookLogin",
                                      "()V"))
    {
        jstring StringArg1 = minfo.env->NewStringUTF(msg);
        minfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(minfo.classID, minfo.methodID);
        minfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(minfo.classID);
    }
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Check out the open source Plugin-X project for Cocos2dx here https://github.com/cocos2d-x/plugin-x You can take an idea of writing all the JNI calls.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue mate, did you have any success with Facebook integration?
Please let me know
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Khash, yes The problem is that You need to put it on the main Actividty from Cocos2dxActivity and assign onEnter act = this. Where act is Cocos2dxActivity, and in any place you call this, you will place act. I will paste code on the answer

Comment: Hi @EduardoIglesias, thanks waiting for the code!

Comment: @Khash I post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem is that You need to put it on the main Actividty from Cocos2dxActivity and assign onEnter act = this. Where act is Cocos2dxActivity, and in any place you call this, you will place act

Code:

```
 public class game extends Cocos2dxActivity{

    static Cocos2dxActivity act;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("Super init");
        act = this;
}

public static void FacebookLogin() {
        Session.openActiveSession(act, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(final Session session2, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session2.isOpened()) {

                    Request.newMeRequest(session2, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                          // callback after Graph API response with user object
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                              Log.d("Facebook", "Hello " + user.getName() + "! Id: "+user.getId());
                              isLoggedIn(); 
                              String mail = (String)response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");
                              if (mail == null) {
                                  mail = "null";
                              }
                              userID(user.getId(), mail, user.getName());
                              session = session2;
                            }
                          }
                    }).executeAsync();

                }
            }
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eduardo,
Thanks for the code, I have a few questions here:
1- What do you mean by main activity? my cocos2dx main activity does not look like this it has "System.loadLibrary("game");".
2- What is session in  "session = session2;" ?
3- What is userID(user.getId(), mail, user.getName()); ?
When I use the exact same code I get this error "This static method cannot hide the instance method from Cocos2dxActivity" and suggests me to remove static.

Comment: @Khash, my methods, userID and isLoggedIn are native methods. You need static, because it will be called from C++. Main Activity,, sorry I mean the main file from your project. "session = session2;" was to check if session has been opened or not. You could eliminate